# Company rank within an industry

Tags: equities, data, market-data, finance, historical-data

I'm looking at the list of companies in the [S&P 500 Pure Value Index](http://us.spindices.com/indices/equity/sp-500-pure-value). For each firm, I want to obtain the dividend yield industry percentile rank and the PEG ratio industry percentile rank.

I've tried Google Finance and Morningstar. The process involves adding by hand specific industry stocks to a portfolio, exporting the data to excel, using percentrank.exc() and vlookup()... Doing this for 100+ stocks in 100+ industries is error prone and can take days.

Is there a faster, more accurate way of obtaining industry rank based on financial data? Does Bloomberg have this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the S&P500 tickers and download the corresponding fields PEG, DivYield, Industry from Bloomberg into Excel.

Then you can just sort the values in excel once by industry and then by PEG to directly see the ranks. You may use two sheets for PEG and DivYield.